# C++ turning a .txt with Hexa characters to a .txt with hexa characters with \x in front

Tags: c++, hex

I would like to ask if there is a method in C++ to turning a .txt file with hexa digits for example

> ```
> 0E 1F BA 0E 00 B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 54 68 69 73 20 70 72
> ```

to a new .txt with that looking

> ```
> \x0E\x1F\xBA\x0E\x00\xB4\x09\xCD\x21\xB8\x01\x4C\xCD\x21\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x70\x72"
> ```

I searched the answer in google but found nothing and tried a script in C++ but does not work with error message "24    11 \x used with no following hex digits"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

string hexaEnter;
ifstream read;
ofstream write;

write.open ("newhexa.txt",std::ios_base::app);

read.open("hexa.txt");

while (!read.eof() )
    {

    read >> hexaEnter;

    write << "\x" + hexaEnter;

    }
write.close();
read.close();

system("pause");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/zrz1YD

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Um, no, this question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong. Once again, please do not abuse your dupehammer. And stop giving the answer in comments!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I should have noticed that when fixing the missing `\\` in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
write << "\x" + hexaEnter;
//        ^^
```

Here, C++ sees the beginning of a hex escape sequence, like `\x0E` or `\x1F`, but it can't find the actual hex values because you didn't provide any.

That's because what you *intended* to do was literally write the character `\` and the character `x`, so escape the backslash to make that happen:

```
write << "\\x" + hexaEnter;
//        ^^^
```

As an aside, [your loop condition is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).